# Point Charge above an Infinite Plate

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

Thanks for reading.

Say we have a point charge $+q$ above an infinite plate. How can we show that the charge that accumulates on the upper surface of the plate is $-q$?

There are two ways I've usually seen this explained.

The first is with image charges...I accept that explanation. However, according to the books I've been learning E&M from, there's a different way...

The other argument I've heard is with a Gaussian cube whose bottom part goes through the plate and top and sides are infinitely far away...but, I don't understand this argument.

I understand that if we make a Gaussian surface that has the bottom inside the plate,then the flux through that bottom part must be zero.

However, I don't buy the argument that if we put the top and sides infinitely far, the flux through them would be zero.

After all, as we grow the Gaussian cube, the areas of the top and the sides would increase proportionally to $r^2$, just as the strength of the electric field would decrease inversely proportionally to $r^2$, where $r$ is the side-length of the cube.

Why is it that the flux through the sides and the top must be zero as well? I don't understand the infinity argument, because if we have an infinitely large sphere with a point charge inside, its not like we can say that the flux through the sphere is zero just because the sphere's walls are infinitely far away?

Thanks!

[image]

**Edit:**

I know that we can show it with the method of images. However, both in Purcell and in Griffiths, the authors hint that the answer could've been arrived at some different way:

**Griffiths:**

[image]

**Purcell:**

[image]

What **is** this different way, and why does it work? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I encourage you to read about the [method of images](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_image_charges), as this answers your first question and is a common problem solving tool in electrostatics. The idea has to do with the [uniqueness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_theorem_for_Poisson%27s_equation), which allows us to treat this system as if there is another negative charge under our (now imaginary) plane, at a distance $d$. This because the electric field generated by this setup is identical for distances above $z=0$ and is thus a unique gradient of a solution to Poisson's equation. Our system looks like this,

[image: imagecharges]

We can then find the Coulomb potential of any point at height $z$ and distance $r$ from the origin in the plane (these are cylindrical coordinates),

$$V(r,z)=\frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\Bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2+(d-z)^2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2+(d+z)^2}}\Bigg)$$

We know $E=-\partial{V}/\partial{z}$, so evaluating on the plane ($z=0$),

$$E(r)=\frac{-q}{2\pi\varepsilon_0}\Bigg(\frac{d}{(r^2+d^2)^{3/2}}\Bigg)$$

By Gauss's Law, the surface charge density on the plane is $\sigma=\varepsilon_0 E$. If we integrate with polar coordinates along the entire plane, we get our induced charge to be,

$$q_{\mathrm{induced}}=-\frac{qd}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty \frac{r\,dr\,d\theta}{(r^2+d^2)^{3/2}}=-q$$

This is indeed the correct answer!

In terms of your second question, no the charge would not be exactly $-q$, but depending on our situation, we could use the method of images to approximate the electric field. Here's a [paper](https://www.ipen.br/biblioteca/cd/ieee/1999/Proceed/00623.pdf) with more information.

Comment: Thank u Archie. I know about the method of images, but both in Purcell and in Griffiths, when they introduce this problem, they claim that we should've expected there to be -Q on the top plate, even before integrating. Why? Thanks again.

Comment: Gauss's Law states $\oint E\cdot\,da \propto q$ where $q$ is the charge enclosed by our Gaussian surface, so the electric flux out of the surface is proportional to the enclosed charge. Imagine a cubic Gaussian surface where the bottom side is fixed at $z=0$, in other words it is $d$ away from the charge w.r.t to the z-axis. If every other side of the cube is expanded to an infinite distance away, the electric field at these sides will be zero ($\lim_{r\to\infty} E=0$) and hence there will be no flux. All flux then passes through the bottom side of our cube, leaving the charge induced as $q$.

Comment: Also, an infinite Gaussian sphere around a point charge would have zero flux coming out of it. This is not a contradiction, because Gauss's Law allows us to treat the electric field generated by some charge distribution as a point charge *outside* of the Gaussian surface. The outside is key. At an infinite distance, the electric field from this point charge is zero. As the radius of our Gaussian sphere approaches infinity, the electric field outside the sphere asymptotically approaches zero, so indeed the flux would be zero at infinity.

Comment: Thanks Archie...sorry, I had forgotten to like your answer, I just did. I appreciate it quite a bit! Regardless, in the infinite Gaussian sphere the area grows inversely proportionally to the decrease of the field-strength...I'm sure the flux wouldn't be zero!

Comment: This question is tricky because if our Gaussian sphere is all space, we don't really have an surface that encloses our charge in the first place. However, if we do the mathematics anyways, electric flux is $\Phi_E = \oint E\cdot\,da$. If we integrate over all space, the limits on our integral are infinite, however our electric field is zero (each da is finite). Flux is the measure of electric field lines coming out of a surface. If there are no field lines, the surface size does not matter: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty 0\,dx=0$. For any finite distance however, the flux indeed will not change.